# Running Dialog inside a loop

Tags: linux, bash, shell, loops, dialog

I have this simple shell script and in it I am using **Dialog** the Linux program to make a dynamic graphical menu for a basic switch-case structure. I launch the program with the following parameters:

```sh
CHOICE=$(dialog --clear \
         --backtitle "$BACKTITLE" \
         --title "$TITLE" \
         --menu "$MENU" \
         $HEIGHT $WIDTH $CHOICE_HEIGHT \
         "${OPTIONS[@]}" \
         2>&1 >/dev/tty)
```

The *Dialog* will exit once I have chosen any of the options of my switch-structure. I would like to run it inside a loop in a way that it would only exit if I press the *cancel*-button. If I put the whole script inside one `while true`-loop then it won't exit once I select *Cancel*.

How can I make a loop that can be exited by selecting *Cancel*? What is the most meaningful way to go on about this? Does *Cancel* return some value that I can use as a parameter for the loop so it can be broken?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from `man dialog`

> No text is written if the Cancel button (or ESC) is pressed; dialog  exits  immediately

yes you can do a loop in your case , and you will test for emptyness .

a example

```
CHOICE="foobar" ; 
while [ -n  "$CHOICE"  ] ; 
do
   CHOICE=$(dialog --clear \
         --backtitle "$BACKTITLE" \
         --title "$TITLE" \
         --menu "$MENU" \
         $HEIGHT $WIDTH $CHOICE_HEIGHT \
         "${OPTIONS[@]}" \
         2>&1 >/dev/tty)
   if [ -n "$CHOICE" ]
   then
      reset
      echo "${CHOICE}"
      sleep 5 
   fi
done
```

Comment: Maybe `echo "${CHOICE}"`?